# What visas I need to travel from Netherlands to Belarus as Russian citizen

Tags: visas, netherlands, russian-citizens, belarus

I am a Russian citizen that currently lives in the Netherlands on MVV visa. I am planning to travel to Belarus. My questions are:

1. Do I need any additional visas to enter Belarus?
2. Do I need any additional visas to enter the Netherlands back?

Comment: If you're flying through a non-Schengen airport that isn't in Russia or Belarus, or otherwise transiting through such a country, then you should check whether you'll need a visa for your transit.

Comment: What permit/visa do you have for Netherlands?

Comment: @VMAtm I have MVV visa valid for 5 years

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not need any visa to enter Belarus. Russian Federation and Belarus form The Eurasian Customs Union, which allows you to even reside and work/study in Belarus.